# Magento 1.8 Flat Product and Category Data

Tags: indexing, flat-catalog

In Magento 1.8.0, the flat product and flat category indexes have been removed.

[image]

Does Magento 1.8 no longer support the flat product and category tables?  If Magento 1.8 **does** support the flat product and category tables, how are these table created and populated?

Comment: product_flat_store and category_flat_store tables are generated and populated, so they seem supported. No triggers in DB, so it must be indexer code, but hidden away

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with Magento CE 1.8 the flat table indexes are only shown on the Index Management  page **if flat tables are enabled**.

Enable flat tables in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend`:

[image: Enable flat tables]

Enjoy the flat table indexes in `System > Index Management`:

[image: Flat table indexes]